# php exec fails when python imports a file

Tags: php, python, exec

I have this code in php:

```
$var = "something";
$result = exec("python /somePath/someFile.py $var");
print $result;
```

and my someFile.py is like this:

```
import functions as f

x = f.removeSpace("hey   there")
print x
```

Now, without the import functions everything is ok, but when I try to import another module then php screws. I have included `sys.stderr = sys.stdout` in my python file, and when I run my php code then it returns:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'removeSpace'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem like this recently. It turned out that PHP's `exec` wasn't passing environment variables through to the program it executed, so Python wasn't seeing `$PYTHONPATH`, and didn't know where to import the module from.

I don't know how to fix that from PHP, but in our case, symlinking the imported package to the same directory as the script made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `functions` module, see if you have defined an `removeSpace` function.

It's not a PHP issue, it's Python issue, you may have forgotten to define that function.

Comment: well the python file works perfectly when I execute it normally

Comment: You said: `Now, without the import functions everything is ok, but when I try to import another module then php screws.` not `when I execute it normally` as you said in this comment!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about `python`, but I think the problem is `someFile.py` can't find your `functions`-module. Because you are executing it from `PHP`, it's `pwd` will be set to `php`'s `pwd`, not `/somePath/`.